# How do I cross-compile C for Raspberry Pi and OpenWrt from Ubuntu?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, openwrt

- I'm working with a RaspberryPi; I have OpenWrt installed on this RaspberryPi.
- I need to execute a C program on OpenWrt.

  - I have my source code on Ubuntu.
  - I know I need to cross-compile the code.

My question is the following:

To run my C program, do I need to cross-compile the code for OpenWrt - or do I need to cross-compile the code for RaspberryPi?

To be more specific, I've found some tutorials about cross-compiling C for RaspberryPi... but does it not depend on the OS (*OpenWrt* in this case)?

Should I follow the cross-compilation for OpenWrt or the simple cross-compilation for RaspberryPi?

Comment: It would help if you could share the C program you're referring to, as well as sharing whatever steps you need to follow to cross-compile.

Comment: A websearch on `cross compile openwrt` produces: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/toolchain/crosscompile and https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/toolchain/crosscompile among many others

Comment: Download the toolchain  Ex: if you are using Pi4 https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/22.03.0/targets/bcm27xx/bcm2711/openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz for your Pi. 
There is a compiler something named `xxxx-musl-gcc`. Assume your C program is just `main.c`. You can compile your program `xxx-gcc main.c` and then you will get your cross-compiled binary.

Comment: I downloaded this toolchain...could you be more specific, please? I'm in directory openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64\toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-11.2.0_musl\bin

Answer (score 0):

Go and download the toolchain for Pi4
https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/22.03.0/targets/bcm27xx/bcm2711/openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz

Unzip and there is a `gcc` compiler

Assume that you have a `main.c` with the following content

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

The real gcc compile is sitting at `openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0`

Use the GCC to compile your `main.c`

`./openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0 main.c`

Compile

```
~/test$ ./openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0 main.c
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc-11.2.0: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
~/test$ ls
a.out
main.c
openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64
openwrt-toolchain-22.03.0-bcm27xx-bcm2711_gcc-11.2.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz
```

Check the executable

```
~/test$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped
```